# Run SQL Select query for date with date time picker in vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, select, datepicker

I am currently working in Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 for Windows Desktop. I am using windows form applications with an SQL back end. I am currently creating a schedule and I need to be able to search a few of the schedules columns with the smalldatetime data type. I am trying to input the date time with a like clause but it does not seem to work. I have tried in the sql server management studio program as well with no success. Here is my code:

```
 MsgBox(DateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy-mmy-dd"))
    Try
        Using conn1 As New SqlConnection(connstring)
            conn1.Open()
            Using comm1 As New SqlCommand("SELECT col1, col2, col3, " _
                    & "col4, col5, col6, col7, col8, " _
                    & "col9, Col10, Col11, Col12, " _
                    & "Col13, Col14, Col15, " _
                    & "Col16, Col17, " _
                    & "Col18, Col19, " _
                    & "Col20, Col21 FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 " _
                    & "ON table2.col2 = table1.col2 Left Join table3 ON " _
                    & "table2.col1 = table3.col2 Left JOIN table4 ON " _
                    & "table2.col5 = table4.col5 WHERE Complete IS NULL" _
                    & " AND " _
                    & "table1.col7 Like '@Date%'", conn1)
                comm1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", DateTime Picker.Value.ToString("yyyy-mm-dd"))
                Dim dt As New DataTable
                Dim sql As New SqlDataAdapter(comm1)
                sql.Fill(dt)
                Datagridview.DataSource = dt
            End Using
            conn1.Close()
        End Using

        Call Paint()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)

    End Try
```

Comment: what is the datatype of col7? datetime?

Comment: it is a smalldatetime column datatype

Comment: So do the dates in the db have a non-zero time, or is it 00:00:00?

Comment: What error do you get? or does it just return no results?

Comment: @TonyHopkinson An example of one of the times in the database is "2015-04-30 07:58:00" or in code "yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss." The thing is, My date time picker was initially throwing me back a date with the current time the date was picked. So for example, if I tried to search table1.col7 for the date 2015-04-30 in my date time picker the actual value the picker was putting out was something like 2015-04-30 03:20:00. So the time would not match up with the searched dates. Then I changed my date time picker to only pick the date and now I cant figure out how to use the Like clause to pull the dates.

Comment: If they were always midnight there was a quick fix client side and change like to equals. Otherwise there were a few ways to do it, the answer you accepted being one of them. Between YYYY-MM-DD:00:00:00 and YYYY-MM-DD:23:59:59 being an nother.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Like statement is really meant for strings.  If col7 is a smalldatetime, then you should really be using some sort of date comparison.  Since you're using Like, my guess is that the column might contain time information and you want all records returned for a particular date.  I don't often use smalldatetime, but with datetime columns, a simple solution is to cast the column as a date and then compare it to a date parameter passed from your DateTime picker.  This of course assumes you're using SQL Server 2008 and above since the date datatype didn't exist until then.

Another solution is to update the where clause to something like the following assuming @Date does not contain time information.

```
table1.col7 >= @Date and table1.col7 < dateadd(day, 1, @Date)
```

Comment: This worked, I had to change my date from lower case mm to upper case MM to distinct the month, will update my code, thanks.